# Eclipse: Avoiding some dependencies to be include in JUnit runtime classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I am working under eclipse Luna:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

I have a project that has some unit tests and depends on other projects in my workspace as well as external dependencies resolved using maven.

The project builds ok, using as one of its dependencies 
.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar

The problem is that, when I try to run unit tests for the project (i.e. right mouse menu on the project's name and selecting "RunAs JUnit") it fails to run throwing the next exception:

```
May 27, 2015 2:06:10 PM com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter doService
SEVERE: service exception:
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:211)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.loadServlet(ServletAdapter.java:456)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.doService(ServletAdapter.java:395)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:349)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapterChain.service(GrizzlyAdapterChain.java:183)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've been reviewing the JUnit runtime classpath using this line as the first in my code:

```
 logger.trace("Execution classpath [" + System.getProperty("java.class.path") + "]");
```

And I've discovered that somehow, these two dependencies are in the classpath:
`.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/4.1/asm-debug-all-4.1.jar:`
`.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/4.0/asm-4.0.jar:`

How can I get rid of them? 
I've read a lot about going to the "Run Configuration" and delete the problematic dependency from the "Classpath" tab, but in my case, the "Classpath" tab only shows the next dependencies:

Bootstrap Entries
 JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7]
User Entries
 MyProblematicProject

Could anyone tell me how to get rid of this annoying dependency or at least sheer a bit of light upon how does eclipse builds the JUnit runtime classpath and what chances are to modify it?

Thank you,

Juan Fra

Answer (score 0):

Most likely something in the project's pom is pulling in those dependencies, transitively. Open the pom file in Eclipse's pom editor and you can use the **Dependency Hierarchy** tab to investigate how you're getting both `asm` versions. From there you can opt to exclude one or both that you don't want/need.

Answer (score 0):

E-Riz, thanks for your reply. Effectively the dependencies are transitively pulled from other projects. They are already located en we have the next lines in our pom:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>websays</groupId>
      <artifactId>common</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>  
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
          <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
          <artifactId>asm-debug-all</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>      
         <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

But, still having this pom config the execution classpath includes org.ow2.asm.asm and org.ow2.asm.asm-debug-all artifact.

Notice that I am always talking about the execution classpath, the build classpath works ok.